# Active Directory Access to remote SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, ldap, cloud, remote-access

I have an environment where a cloud based server is hosting a SQL Database. Users connect directly to this in order to run queries and download data.

Rather than setting up user logins and assigning them to roles manually I'd like to inherit these from the company Active Directory account. I can get LDAP credentials on the remote SQL Database but I'm unclear on how I can use this to provide login access for the users (and to correctly assign them to roles).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of SSIS. Please check the below link for the same.
[Importing data from Active Directory Using SSIS](http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/05/importing-data-from-active-directory-using-ssis/)

Comment: That approach uses AD as a datasource (for a data flow task or similar) I'm looking to dynamically create a login for SQL (or pass the credentials through) automatically when logging on in management studio or similar.

Comment: As per my knowledge, create different AD groups depending on the level of security you need. And add users to these AD groups as per the access you want to give to them and grant security access to the AD groups that you like in SSMS. So the type of access that you provide to AD group will reflect to the users who are in that AD group.This is how it works in my organization.

Comment: You're assuming the fact that the SQL Server host is on the same network as the normal active directory network - which in this case it is not. Specifically the SQL Server account is a cloud based vm with no formal connectivity to AD.